# Can't find "Site Configuration > Image Caption" configuration settings

Tags: 7, media

Can't find "Site Configuration > Image Caption" configuration after image_caption has been installed.

I installed latest version of image_caption from https://www.drupal.org/project/image_caption.

The module is enabled but no configuration settings.

Under Configuration, there is no input filter.
[image]

In text format, can't find any image caption settings.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D7 version of module doesn't provide configuration under "Admin => Site Configuration => Image Caption". "**Site Configuration**" was available in D6 version, in D7 it is called as "**Configuration**".

I've just tried the D7 version of module, there are 2 modules and it is as below:

1. **Image caption** (main module) : This module doesn't define any configuration, it by default check if `<img>` tag in page body has `caption` class or not. If yes, then it takes the `title` attribute value and add caption.
2. **Image caption filter** (sub-module) : This module defines configuration under ***Admin => Configuration => Text Formats*** settings (see screenshot below). To process the images uploaded in Text Area.
   [image: Image Caption Filter Settings]

Comment: There is no input filter under configuration. I have attached the image in question.

Comment: **_Text Formats_** are **_Input Filters_**. I've also updated ans above.

Comment: I have go to Text Formats settings, but no image caption. I have attached the related image in question.

Comment: I've just tried the module, and updated the answer with finding. Please check.

Comment: Thanks. I have activate it in Text Format. How do I add caption in text editor?